# ¿Como saber si el usuario tiene la sesión iniciada?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel, autenticación

Quiero saber el usuario tiene la sesión iniciada para mostrar o no ciertas cosas en la vista.

Puedo hacer la opción de que en un menú se vea que si el usuario que tiene la sesión iniciada es administrador muestre un boton hacía el panel de administración.

```
@if(Auth::user()->tipoUsuario == 'Administrador')
        <li><a href="/admin/usuario">Administración</a></li>
@endif
```

Lo  que quiero hacer es ver si un usuario cualquiera tenga la sesión activa para mostrar ciertas cosas.

Comment: "mostrar ciertas cosas", a que te refieres, mostrar ciestar rutas de la paginas o mostrar ciertos elementos en una página?

Comment: me gustaria que fueras mas detallista con lo que pides en cuanto a que es lo que quieres mostrar o no, y asi poderte dar una respuesta que se adapte a lo que pides

Comment: Si, lo que quería hacer era como saber si había un usuario con la sesión iniciada, porque por ejemplo no voy a mostrar el botón de cerrar sesión si no hay sesión iniciada. No se si me entiendas mejor.

Comment: Quizá se podría trabajar con roles en Laravel. Aquí una referencia muy buena que te podría ayudar.
https://medium.com/@cvallejo/autenticaci%C3%B3n-de-usuarios-y-roles-en-laravel-5-5-97ab59552d91

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En estos momento yo tambien tengo la misma cuestion

He creado varios Auth::guard usando https://github.com/Hesto/multi-auth

cada tipo de usuario tiene una tabla diferente y dependiendo del tipo de usuario se muestran diferentes opciones, por lo que las opciones Auth::guest() (que da true si no esta logueado) y Auth::check() da true o false porlo que necesito al mas especifico para cada tipo de usuario

Gracias

ACTUALIZACION

encontre una solucion para determinar que mostrará en funcion del tipo de usuario

```
    @if(Auth::guard('trader')->check())
                            ES UN TRADER
                        @elseif(Auth::guard('admin')->check())
                            ES UN ADMIN
                        @endif
```

Donde "trader" y "admin" son mis Auth::guard

Answer (score 2):

algo mas completo. podes hacer

```
 @if (Auth::guest())
                    <li><a href="{{ url('admin/auth/login') }}">Login</a></li>                   
  @else
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
     {{ Auth::user()->name }}<b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Mi perfil</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li>
         <a href="{{ url('/logout') }}"
                onclick="event.preventDefault();
                document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                Logout
         </a>
         <form id="logout-form" action="{{ url('admin/auth/logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                                </form>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  @endif
```

Esta basado en el que trae por default cuando haces make:auth

Answer (score 2):

Sencillo:

```
@if (Auth::guest())
    <li><a href="{{ url('admin/auth/login') }}">Login</a></li>                   
@else
    <li><a href="/admin/usuario">Administración</a></li>
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@if( Auth::guest() )
 <li><a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a></li>
 <li><a href="{{ url('/registrar') }}">Registrar</a></li>
@else
 <li><a href="/{{Auth::user()->tipoUsuario}}">Administración</a></li>
@endif
```

Siempre que navegamos por la aplicación con Laravel tendremos la variable Auth, si no iniciamos sesión, por defecto contendrá el objeto guest(), y si nos identificamos como ususarios, es decri, iniciamos una sesión laravel creará el objeto user() en el cual se almacenan laspropiedades o los datos del usuario.

Si queremos saber si el usuario no se ha identifiacado iniciando una sesión simplemente comprobamos la existencia del objeto Auth::guest(). Si no existe significa que algún usuario registrado ha iniciado sesión y podremos acceder a los datos dentro del objeto.

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], pues responde con solo código se considera de baja calidad

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio ! , Ayudanos agregando una explicación de lo que realiza el código y de que forma ayudaría a resolver el problema planteado, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Yo he implementado lo siguiente en mi proyecto:

```
  @if(Auth::check()) //En mi caso solo uso un tipo de usuario, verifico si hay una cuenta logueada
        <a href="{{ route('admin') }}">
        <button class="btn btn-danger"><h4>Administrador</h4></button>
    </a> //Si se cumple entonces, muestro el botón para ir al panel de administrador

    @else sino muestro un boton para loguear

    <a href="{{route('login')}}">
        <button class="btn btn-danger"><h4>Iniciar sesión</h4></button>
    </a>
    @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Asi quedo finalmente

```
@if (Auth::guest())
    <a href="/login" class="scrollto">Ingresa</a>
@else
    @if(auth()->user()->role->name === "admin")
        <a href="/base" class="scrollto">Administrar</a>
    @endif
@endif
```

Answer (score -2):

Usando

```
@if (Auth::check())

@endif
```

Mediante ese if podemos saber si hay alguien con la sesión iniciada.

Comment: No creo que esta sea la mejor respuesta :S